# ListView OnItemClickListener not working with custom array adapter

Tags: android, listview

Hi I've been working on android app which needs to use different type of list view items For this I implemented  custom array adapter to handle multiple custom list item once And here are my code snippets:
Custom Array Adapter

```
public class QuestionsCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
public static final int ImageQuestion=0;
public static final int TextQuesiton=1;
public static final int VideoQuestion=2;


private List<ListViewItem> questions;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public QuestionsCustomAdapter(Activity activity,int res,List<ListViewItem> questions){
    super(activity,res,questions);
    mInflater=(LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.questions=questions;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return questions.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return questions.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public Integer getItemViewType1(int position){
    return questions.get(position).getType();
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CustomViewHolder viewHolder=null;

    int listViewItemType=getItemViewType1(position);

        if(listViewItemType==ImageQuestion){
            convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view_image,null);
            ListViewItem listViewItem=questions.get(position);
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageAnswer2)).setText(listViewItem.getAnswer1());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageAnswer3)).setText(listViewItem.getAnswer2());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageAnswer4)).setText(listViewItem.getAnswer3());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageAnswer5)).setText(listViewItem.getAnswer4());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageQuestionText)).setText(listViewItem.getQuestion());
            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listViewItem.getImageAndVideoView());
            ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardImage)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardImage)).setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rightImageAnswer)).setText("Right answer: "+listViewItem.getRightAnswer());
        }else if(listViewItemType==TextQuesiton){
            convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view,null);
            ListViewItem listViewItem1=questions.get(position);
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.answer2)).setText(listViewItem1.getAnswer1());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.answer3)).setText(listViewItem1.getAnswer2());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.answer4)).setText(listViewItem1.getAnswer3());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.answer5)).setText(listViewItem1.getAnswer4());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionText)).setText(listViewItem1.getQuestion());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rightAnswer)).setText("Right answer:"+listViewItem1.getRightAnswer());
        }else if(listViewItemType==VideoQuestion){
            convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view_video,null);
            ListViewItem listViewItem2=questions.get(position);
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.videoAnswer2)).setText(listViewItem2.getAnswer1());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.videoAnswer3)).setText(listViewItem2.getAnswer2());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.videoAnswer4)).setText(listViewItem2.getAnswer3());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.videoAnswer5)).setText(listViewItem2.getAnswer4());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.videoQuestionText)).setText(listViewItem2.getQuestion());
            ((VideoView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardViewVideo)).setVideoURI(Uri.parse(listViewItem2.getImageAndVideoView()));
            ((VideoView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardViewVideo)).seekTo(100);
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rightVideoAnswer)).setText("Right Answer: "+listViewItem2.getRightAnswer());
        }

    return convertView;
}
```

}
And here are my ListView listener:

```
 listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
 customAdapter=new QuestionsCustomAdapter(this,0,questions1);
 listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Bundle position=new Bundle();
            ListViewItem itemValue=(ListViewItem) listView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            Integer questionType=itemValue.getType();


            String[] questionArray={itemValue.getQuestion(),itemValue.getAnswer1(),itemValue.getAnswer2(),itemValue.getAnswer3(),
            itemValue.getAnswer4(),itemValue.getRightAnswer(), String.valueOf(i)};
            position.putStringArray("question",questionArray);
            position.putString("type","edit");
            position.putString("questionType",String.valueOf(itemValue.getType()));
            if(itemValue.getType()==0){
                position.putString("image",itemValue.getImageAndVideoView());
            }else if(itemValue.getType()==2){
               position.putString("video",itemValue.getVideoView());
            }
            DialogFragment editQuestionFragment=EditQuestionFragment.newInstance();

            editQuestionFragment.setArguments(position);
            editQuestionFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"dialog");
        }
    });
```

This listener works with **card_view_image** and **card_view** but **card_view_video** item not respond listener.

Comment: then debug what this itemValue.getType() returns?

Comment: Nothing I forgot to mention when I was debugging clicking the card_view_video item not triggering listener while other items trigger listener.

Comment: you'll have to override getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType() in your adapter to correctly support different item types

Comment: Thats not the problem I can add new card_view_video item in listview but cant click on them @PrfctByDsgn